# How to export UVs per-vertex in script (as OBJ format does)?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, export, vertices

OpenGL (the model's final destination) only accepts per-vertex UVs, so it is a *must* to use per-vertex and not "per face-vertex" UVs. The question isn't about OGL, that's just my reasoning. The OBJ format stores UVs per-vertex, proving that it is possible. I also have checked the code of the default OBJ exporter. However, it's UV exporting code is completely reliant on the rest of it's code making it very difficult to read and understand the default OBJ exporter script.

Current code for exporting UVs:

```
for face in mesh.polygons:
    for vert, loop in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
        if (vert in usedverts):
            print("duplicate")
        else:
            for z in (mesh.uv_layers.active.data[loop].uv if mesh.uv_layers.active is not None else (0.0, 0.0)):
                f.write(struct.pack('f', z))
```

It doesn't export them correctly, whether or not I use the `if (vert in usedverts):`. I think because when removing duplicates, they end up in the wrong order or something like that. Maybe someone has a better example of per vertex UV exporting [than the confusing default obj exporter]?

Comment: I think the "per vertex" you mention here is incorrect (and logically impossible). I'm not experimented so much in openGL, but to me, UV coord has to be defined accordingly to the 3D faces definitions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a openGL programming problem which is not directly related to Blender's usage, function or scripting.

Comment: Yes it is, it's related to writing exporting scripts.

Comment: Please see my first comment. In this script you'll have to export per face data. In order to recompose faces 3D coordinates and its corresponding us coordinates.

Comment: Edited my question a lot. @lemon OBJ format exports per-vertex UVs.

Comment: Another question: how do you plan to interpret the exported data in your *external* opengl program? I mean about opengl tri, quad, fan, polygons.

Comment: @lemon OpenGL only takes vertexes, indices, and any other *attributes* a vertex may have. A UV coord is an example of an attribute, and is why it must be per-vertex.

Comment: Accumulator, I think the confusion is due to 'per vertex' notion is not the same in Blender and OpenGL. So I need to repeat my question (in order to help giving an answer to your question): by which mean do you want to use this data export in your OpenGL program?

Comment: @lemon For texture coordinates. To clear up what I mean by per vertex, I mean each vertex is individually processed and and then the texture is sampled at that vertex's UV coord and interpolated across the face. Not sure if it is the same in blender.

Comment: I'll try an answer to clarify... even if this answer is not what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57631/discussion-between-lemon-and-accumulator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to use UV coordinates with OpenGL, at some step, you'll have to use instructions like this one:

```
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);

   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(2.41421, 1.0, -1.41421);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(2.41421, -1.0, -1.41421);
   glEnd();
```

Which means that:

- UV coordinates are given per vertex...
- ... but given per vertex only in the scope of a drawn face

So we have, in fact a per face information.

In your export program, you may:

- Loop over the vertices to store their coordinates
- Loop over the faces to store the vertices they use (e.g. making fan polygons)
- Loop over the UV maps, and for each:
- Loop over the polygons (at obj.data level)
- Loop over each polygon's loop_indices and take the corresponding data (uv coordinates) in the current UV map.

This can be something like this (code template):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object #An object (selected one)

#Write 3D coordinates
for v in obj.data.vertices: 
    #Write v.co in your file
    pass

#Write polygons (faces)
for p in obj.data.polygons: 
    #Write a line per polygon indicating the vertices it uses
    for i in p.vertices:
        #Write i in your file  
        #See explanation 1 below  
    pass

#Write each uv map
for uvMap in obj.data.uv_layers:
    #Process this uvMap
    for p in obj.data.polygons:
        #Use the polygon loop indices
        for li in p.loop_indices:
            #Write the uv coordinates for each vertex in the uv map
            uvMap.data[li].uv
            #See explanation 2 below
```

Explanation 1 (see comments in code):

The indices stored here refer to the previously written 3D coordinates in the same order they've been written

Explanation 2 (see comments in code):

The uv coordinates stored here correspond to the polygons vertices indices in the same order they are written previously in the polygons part

Comment: My problem is, each vertex is only processed once, so only one UV coord can be used for any given vertex, so any repeating UVs will break everything. A vertex is not processed again when drawing another face, so using indice-based UVs isn't possible, if that's what you're suggesting (is it)? So if blender will only give indice based UVs which which includes repeats, I need a way to sort them into a list that is in the same order of the vertex they correspond to

Comment: There is a discussion link in the comments below your question above, please use it so that we can talk about it